# Left join does not return ull values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

AppWindowsEvent:

```
CREATE TABLE [AppWindowsEvent]
(
[idAppWindowEvent]      INT IDENTITY(1,1)
, [idAppWindow]         INT
, [idEventType]         INT
, [Order]               INT
, CONSTRAINT PK_idAppWindowEvent PRIMARY KEY ([idAppWindowEvent])
, CONSTRAINT FK_idAppWindowEvent_AppWindow FOREIGN KEY ([idAppWindow]) REFERENCES [AppWindow]([idAppWindow])
, CONSTRAINT FK_idAppWindowEvent_EventType FOREIGN KEY ([idEventType]) REFERENCES [EventType]([idEventType])
)
```

Event:

```
CREATE TABLE [Event]       
(
[idEvent] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
, [idEventType] [INT] NOT NULL
, [idEntity] [INT] NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT PK_IdEvent PRIMARY KEY([idEvent])
, CONSTRAINT [FK_Event_EventType] FOREIGN KEY([idEventType]) REFERENCES [EventType] ([idEventType])
)
```

When i run this query:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
AppWindowsEvent AWE
LEFT JOIN Event E ON AWE.idEventType = E.idEventType
WHERE
AWE.idMill = 1
AND AWE.idAppWindow = 1
ORDER BY
AWE.[Order] ASC
```

The result: not return nulls.

And when i run this

```
SELECT
*
FROM
AppWindowsEvent AWE
LEFT JOIN Event E ON AWE.idEventType = E.idEventType
AND E.[idEntity] = 1234
WHERE
AWE.idMill = 1
AND AWE.idAppWindow = 1
ORDER BY
AWE.[Order] ASC
```

Result: return nulls.

NOTE:
I need the entire set of data that are and are not already configured, in case you want a specific set of events, in the AND of ON can be filtered by specific idEntity of the Event table and the result returns well, but only for that idEntity, in my case I need all idEntity.

Comment: Does your keyboard have some psychological issue that forces it to jam on the capslock key while typing titles?

Comment: I don't see how making the `ON` criteria _more_ restrictive should result in `NULL` values suddenly appearing.

Comment: --Please Try the code below
SELECT *
FROM AppWindowsEvent AWE
LEFT JOIN Event E ON AWE.idEventType = E.idEventType
 AND E.[idEntity] = 1234
 AND AWE.idMill = 1
 AND AWE.idAppWindow = 1
ORDER BY AWE.[Order] ASC

Comment: Are you sure it is not the other way round?

Comment: It's making nulls appear because there are probably lots of events of a given type (which is the main condition of the ON clause) but none for that  idEntity for certain event types.  I suggest, without seeing the data or understanding fully what is captured there, that this join is bogus, and that you should instead be joining on "AWE.idAppWindowEvent = E.idEvent", not on the types of events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM
AppWindowsEvent AWE
LEFT JOIN Event E ON AWE.idEventType = E.idEventType 
WHERE
AWE.idMill = 1
AND AWE.idAppWindow = 1
AND E.[idEntity] = 1234
ORDER BY
AWE.[Order] ASC
```

Or if you doesn't want appear null valor in second table, you can use Inner Join instead Left Join

```
SELECT *
FROM
AppWindowsEvent AWE
Inner JOIN Event E ON AWE.idEventType = E.idEventType 
AND E.[idEntity] = 1234
WHERE
AWE.idMill = 1
AND AWE.idAppWindow = 1
ORDER BY
AWE.[Order] ASC
```